# percentage margin issue in chrome & IE

Tags: css, percentage

I have built a slider which expands to fit the window, and have `#prev` and `#next` pager buttons (which are highlighted in green). As the slider changes size I need to have these buttons positioned with a top margin as a percentage value. This is fine in Firefox but in Chrome and IE it doesn't read this margin. If I put it as a px value it works fine but obviously doesn't adjust to fit the slider size. Please advise...

http://subzerostudio.com/Clients/perkinreveller/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Chris, instead of regularly changing the **margin-top** value, you could instead modify the **top** value regularly.

Since you've positioned the two buttons as absolute, it's better to work with left and top values instead of margins - frankly because margins don't make much sense once you're at liberty to use left,top,right,bottm values in CSS.

Hope this helps you. I tried removing margins in both Chrome and FF and they both looked the same after that. Once you get to this position, you can then modify the **top** values.

Comment: Hi Aditya, thanks a lot for that. I have swapped the top and margin-top values around and it doesn't seem to read the top: percentage value at all ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try absolutely positioning the buttons with a "top" value of 50% then a negative margin top of the height in pixels of the button.

If you make the buttons a relatively small fixed size that doesn't change then this will be do-able.

That seems to be how Flexi-SLider works and that is one of the leading responsive sliders out there.

http://flexslider.woothemes.com/